How to find the $\mathbb Q$ conjugates?
This question is in the textbook: Abstract Algebra, A Comprehensive Introduction by John W. Lawrence and Frank A. Zorzitto.
Find the $\mathbb{Q}$-conjugates of $\alpha = 7^{1/3}+2i$.
I am trying to show that there are only 2 such conjugates, but am struggling to show that no more than 2 exist.
I have already shown that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Q}[7^{1/3},i]$, the degree $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]=6$, and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ being $X^6+12X^4-14X^3+48X^2+168X+113$.
In order to find the conjugates, I think I am supposed to extract all the solutions from the minimal polynomial. But some of these solutions will contain $\zeta$, the primitive 3-rd root of unity, which I am pretty sure we discard since $\zeta$ is not in our desired field extension. Then we only consider the automorphisms on $i$, namely the identity and the additive inverse mapping. So are there only 2 conjugates, being $\alpha$ itself and $7^{1/3}-2i$?

Also I am pretty sure the splitting field is Q[∛7±2i,∛7 ζ±2i,∛7 ζ^2±2i] but I don't know how to show this with the theory I know so far. I know probably we should consider the roots of the minimal polynomials of ∛7 and i separately.

I think I need to make use of this proposition: If L is a field extension of F, f in F[X] with positive degree and R being the seet of roots of f which lie in L, then the restriction of every F-map phi:L->L is a permutation of R.

Why should there be only two conjugates? $7^{1/3}$ is one of three conjugates. $2i$ is one of two cnjugates. I'd expect six conjugates, all told.

Do study this.

What's the definition of a $\Bbb{Q}$-conjugate for you? I think it normally makes a reference to some extension field (like: $\Bbb{Q}$-conjugates inside $L$). If no other $L$ is specified, my instincts suggest to me that $L$ should contain a splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

@JyrkiLahtonen I checked the book he mentioned and the above problem doesn't specify which extension to find the conjugate ( though in the definitions they defined conjugate in some fixed extension). I guess the book is just not clear enough.

Let $K$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $$f(X) = X^6+12X^4-14X^3+48X^2+168X+113$$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.
We denote $\beta$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-conjugate of $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{7}+2i$ in $K$. Then there exists a $\mathbb{Q}-$map $\psi \colon K \to K$ such that  $\psi(\alpha) = \beta.$
This is Proposition 6.36 in the book you are using.
Clearly we have $$\psi(\alpha) = \psi\left(\sqrt[3]{7}+2i\right) = \psi\left(\sqrt[3]{7}\right) + 2\cdot\psi\left(i\right),$$
it is enough to find $\psi\left(\sqrt[3]{7}\right)$ and $2\cdot\psi\left(i\right)$ to determine the possible values of $\beta$. Since $\psi$ is a $\mathbb{Q}-$map, it fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ pointwisely. As a consequence, we have
$$\psi\left(\sqrt[3]{7}\right)^3 - 7 = \psi(7)-7 = 7 - 7 =0$$
Thus $\psi$ permutes the set of roots of $x^3-7$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, namely $$\psi\left(\sqrt[3]{7}\right) \in \left\lbrace \sqrt[3]{7},\omega\sqrt[3]{7},\omega^2\sqrt[3]{7}\right\rbrace, $$
where $\omega = e^{2i\pi/3}$. A similar computation yields $\psi(i) \in \left\lbrace \pm i\right\rbrace$.
Note that over $K$, the polynomial $f$ has $6$ distinct roots, or, six $  \mathbb{Q}-$ conjugates in $K$. Let's call these conjugates $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_6$. By Prop $6.36$, each $\beta_i$ gives rise to a $\mathbb{Q}-$ map $\psi_i \colon K \to K$ such that $\beta_i = \psi_i(\alpha)$. Repeat the same argument for each $\psi_i$ as for $\psi$ above, we have
$$\left\lbrace \psi_1(\alpha),\ldots, \psi_6(\alpha)\right\rbrace \subset \left\lbrace \sqrt[3]{7} \pm 2i,\omega\sqrt[3]{7}\pm 2i,\omega^2\sqrt[3]{7} \pm 2i\right\rbrace, $$
which implies two sets must be equal, as they both contain $6$ elements.
Overall, there are six choices of $\beta$, corresponding to $6$ distinct roots of the polynomial $f(X)$.
So if you are asking about $\mathbb{Q}-$conjugate of $\alpha$ in the splitting field $K$, there are $6$ conjugates, namely
$$\left\lbrace \sqrt[3]{7} \pm 2i,\omega\sqrt[3]{7}\pm 2i,\omega^2\sqrt[3]{7} \pm 2i\right\rbrace $$
If you are asking about  $\mathbb{Q}-$conjugate in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, then there are only $2$ of them since the only possible conjugate of $\sqrt[3]{7}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is itself.
What is the splitting field $K$? I claim that $$K = \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\omega\right) =\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right)$$
It is easy to check that $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right] = 12$ and $f$ splits over $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right)$. So $K \subset \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right)$. On the other hand, $K$ strictly contains $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, thus $[K:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \ge 2$. Hence
$$[K:\mathbb{Q}] = [K:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] \ge 12 = [\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right):\mathbb{Q}]$$
Combining with the observation $K \subset\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right)$ ,we can conclude that $K=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7},i,\sqrt{3}\right). $

Where did $\sqrt{3}$ come from?

@IanBendig $\omega = -1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2$, so I can represent $\sqrt{3}$ using $\omega$ and $i$

Can you explain the logic that when we collect the conjugates of $7^{1/3},i$ separetely, and up their conjugates that that accounts for all roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (or I guess I could say the conjugates of $\alpha$). I was trying to figure it out from the propositions in the book and properties of homomorphisms but to no avail. I hope that makes sense.

Is there a result in the text that says that all the automorphisms are given by the process in Proposition 6.36 or was I just supposed to know this?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
